Could efficient solutions of $x^2+n y^2=A$ be related to integer factorization?
Let $n$ be positive integer with unknown factorization and $A$ integer with known
factorization.
According to pari/gp developers pari can efficiently find all solutions of:
$$x^2+n y^2=A \qquad (1)$$
To achieve this, we need the factorization of $A$.
$A$ is prime with probability $\log{A}$ and also with high
probability we can find $A$ which is product of small primes
and one additional large prime.
We can choose $(x,y)=(x_0,y_0)$ which guarantees one solution
and experimentally sometimes there are more than one solution
up to sign, but our experimental data is not enough.
There is the obvious congruence $x_0^2 \equiv A \pmod{n}$
and if we have second solution $(x_1,y_1)$ with $x_0 \ne \pm x_1 \pmod{n}$
we can find proper factor of $n$.
The pari code is sol=qfbsolve(Qfb(1,0,n),A,3)

Q1 Can efficient solutions of this form lead to
subexponential integer factorization algorithm?


This idea goes back a long way, even back to Euler and Gauss.  See Chapter 10 of Buell's 'Binary Quadratic Forms: Classical Theory and Modern Computations'.  The title of Chapter 10 is 'Factoring with Binary Quadratic Forms'

The PARI developers are aware of this connection.  When they say they can efficiently find solutions of (1), they are not making a specific claim about the run time.

@Stopple about the running time:  I tried it with 1000 digits composite n and prime A and it took very short time. I call this efficient.

Short answer: no, what you propose does not work. A related method does work, and is already well-known.
Full answer:
Since the goal is factorisation, let us assume $n$ has no small prime factors and $A,n$ are coprime.
The standard algorithm to solve $x^2+ny^2=A$ goes as follows:

factor $A$
find all square roots of $-n$ modulo $A$ (using the factorisation)
for each such square root $s$, look for solutions $(x,y)$ such that $x-sy\equiv 0 \bmod A$ by computing a short vector in the corresponding lattice.

All those steps can be performed efficiently, except possibly for the factorisation of $A$. So if you feed the algorithm with integers $A$ that are easy to factor, then it will be efficient.
The reason why the method does not work is because there will almost never be a solution. Indeed, square roots $s$ in the algorithm above correspond exactly to ideals of norm $A$ in the ring $R=\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-n}]$, and the last step is a test for principality of such an ideal. However, the size of the class group of $R$ is about $\sqrt{n}$, so the probability that you will find a solution is about $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$, exponentially small, a fact that you probably observed if you tested your method.
The variant that does work comes from the last interpretation in terms of ideals and the class group of $R$. A nice class of $A$ that are easy to factor are smooth numbers: choose a smoothness bound $Y$, and take $A$ all of whose prime factors are less than $Y$. As explained above, fixing $A$ and looking for solutions does not work. However, what does work is to draw many random pairs $(x,y)$ until $x^2+ny^2$ is smooth. This way, one produces relations among the prime ideals of $R$ of norm at most $Y$, and assuming those ideals generate the class group, one can eventually compute the class group of $R$. This is essentially the algorithm of Hafner and McCurley, which indeed runs in subexponential time $\exp(O(\sqrt{\log n \log\log n}))$. Once this is done, one can factor $n$ as follows: $2$-torsion elements in the class group will give you squarefree numbers $A$ such that your equation has no solution for $A$, but has one for $A^2$, yielding $(x,y)$ such that $x^2+ny^2 = A^2$, and therefore $(x-A)(x+A) \equiv 0 \bmod n$. Gauss's genus theory tells you that there will be enough $2$-torsion elements to factor $n$ this way. The resulting method is closely related to the quadratic sieve factoring algorithm.
Edit to substantiate my claim that this is well-known: this is Seysen's algorithm in the paper A probabilistic factorization algorithm with quadratic forms of negative discriminant. Math. Comput. 48, 757-780 (1987) (DOI link).

Many thanks this works.
